# No missing values, but during KNN R converts them to NA values

Tags: r, na, knn

For the life of me I cannot figure out why R suddenly converts my values to NA.

```
library(class)
attach(alcohol)
trainknn=cbind(Pstatus, absences, internet)[testsamples,]
testknn=cbind(Pstatus, absences, internet)[-testsamples,]
**trainknn.Walc=test$Walc[testsamples]**
set.seed(1)
knn.pred=knn(trainknn, testknn, trainknn.Walc, k=6)
knn.predtest=sample(knn.pred,57,replace=T)
```

The line with ** is the one giving me trouble (obviously the stars are not in my actual code). I split the training and test data up in code not listed here, but I'm fairly certain that's alright. When I ask to print Walc, all the values are there. When I print test$Walc, all the values are there. It's only when I add [testsamples] when it suddenly returns almost all NA values. Anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: here's how I split up the data

```
set.seed(1)
testsamples=sample(1:nrow(alcohol), size=.10*nrow(alcohol))
test=alcohol[testsamples,]
train=alcohol[-testsamples,]
nrow(test)
```

Comment: What is `testsamples`? Are the indices the same as in `test`? If you subset a vector by index using indices that are beyond the range of the vector, those will return NA. If `testsamples` refers to indices in the un-split dataset, while `test` is split (and thus shorter), some of the indices in `testsamples` might not appear in `test`. As an example, try `mtcars$mpg[c(1,999)]` which returns `21 NA`

Comment: @divibisan I added my code for splitting up the data..

Comment: What are the dimensions of `test` and `alcohol`?

Comment: It's split into a 10% test set... test is 64 x 33 and alcohol is the main data set which is 649 x 33

Answer (score 1):

When you try to subset a vector with indices that don't exist, it will return `NA` for those values. You can see this with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
# mtcars$mpg is a vector 32 items long:
length(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 32
```

When you subset using square bracket notation using indices < 32, it returns the apropriate values. When you use an index outside the range (such as 999 below) it returns `NA`:

```
mtcars$mpg[c(1,14,21,999)]
[1] 21.0 15.2 21.5   NA
```

---

In your example, you use `sample` to pick 64 random rows from `alcohol` by row number. You then use this to subset `alcohol` into `test`, which only has 64 rows. When you then try to subset `test` using `testsamples`, you're requesting rows that don't exist in `test` since it's shorter. In those cases, you get `NA` instead of the requested row.